# Geotiff for Elevation Data or NetCDF

Tags: climate-models, mapping

I need elevation data with lat and long for a project worldwide. By intuition I would say that a GeoTiff would be suitable, e.g. the one from https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp.

Are there better ones, or does this one not contain any elevation data? Does anyone know where there are open source Geotiffs that are good? Or are there open source CSV files that contain the required information, or similar?

ps. I only need the surface data from the mainland, not from the oceans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Better' will depend on your planned usage - any global product will have limitations in terms of overall accuracy and precision, and both the Aster photogrammetric data and the widely used [radar SRTM data](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) don't have data at the poles. The [Copernicus GLO-90 DEM](https://spacedata.copernicus.eu/web/cscda/dataset-details?articleId=394198) is an alternative. At full resolution these are large datasets, so you may want to seek out a reduced resolution dataset, e.g. the [1km gridded NASA data](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/srtm30-global-1-km-digital-elevation-model-dem-version-11-land-surface).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer: Is there a Geotiff wich only have the data for the land and not from the oceans?

Comment: Not sure you will find that in a global model - so you might need to filter a global dataset by a land cover dataset that defines ocean

Comment: ok sounds complicaded! but thanks

Comment: Actually I think the 1km gridded NASA data is a land surface only dataset, so I guess fits your requirement